# Proof the existence of a specific linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem states the following:
Let $V$ be a $F$-vector-space and let $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Proof the existence of a linear transformation  $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that $T(x_i)=x_i+x_{i-1}$. With $i=1,2,...,n$. Where $x_0:=0$. And then calculate the matrix of that linear transformation with respect to $\beta$ and $x_i \in V$.

My attempt  was to write $x_i=\sum _{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j}v_j$. Then applied $T(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i,j}T(v_j)$ and set them equal to $x_i+x_{i-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{i,j}+a_{i-1,j})v_j$. But I can not find an expression for $T$.

I also try to write the list, but it was useless. Any ideas? Maybe it is not possible. Any help is gratefully welcome (:

Comment: I know what $v_i$s are, but what are $x_i$s?

Comment: They must be elements of V. But the other answer suggest that first we must difine x's

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterexample. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $x_2=e_2$ 
and $x_3={\it 0}$. Then for any linear map $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$,
$$T(x_3)={\it 0}\neq {\it 0}+e_2=x_3+x_2.$$
So the vectors $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ must be determined.

Comment: You are right, we must add an extra condition. What if we state that no $x_i$ is equal to zero. I have find an easy solution if the $a_i$ of every $v_i$ is  non-zero